# Is it possible to get Websocket connection Origin from a javax.websocket.Session instance?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I am using jetty's jsr356 WebSocket API implementation in my WebSocket server, for some reason, I'd like to be able to get the connection Origin value via  current `javax.websocket.Session` object.

I know I can get the origin while the connection establishing inside the server endpoint `Configurator`, but can I get it from the session object after a message arrived?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the connection origin?

Comment: Sorry I may not make it clear, origin means the http header "origin" value, it's usually the websocket client host name, a string like `http://example.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Origin` header is sent during WebSocket upgrade handshake, and you can choose to either accept/deny the websocket upgrade with a custom `Configurator`, and/or capture and store the `Origin` in the User Properties for that upgrade for later use by the `session.getUserProperties()`

Look at [`javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html).

You can use the [Configurator.checkOrigin(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#checkOrigin-java.lang.String-) to validate the origin header at upgrade time, it is used to allow/deny the upgrade.

You can also use the [`Configurator.modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig, HandshakeRequest, HandshakeResponse)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#modifyHandshake-javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig-javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest-javax.websocket.HandshakeResponse-) to capture the `Origin` head and place it into the UserProperties map for later access.

eg:

```java
@Override
public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, 
                            HandshakeRequest request, 
                            HandshakeResponse response)
{
    sec.getUserProperties().put("TheUpgradeOrigin",request.getHeaders().get("Origin"));
    // Note: this store a List<String> in the key "TheUpgradeOrigin"
}
```

And then later in your endpoint ...

```java
@OnMessage
public String onTextMessage(Session session, String msg)
{
    List<String> originHeader = (List<String>)session.getUserProperties()
                                                     .get("TheUpgradeOrigin");

    // Do something with this header

    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Origin` header is just a piece of input sent by the client, so it can't be trusted. In well-behaving browsers (with developer extensions disabled, of course!) that value is used to tell the hostname the client script was downloaded from. That said, you can query the headers of the upgrade request on the [`Session`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session.html) object:

```
String origin = session.getUpgradeRequest().getHeader("Origin");
```

Comment: session.getUpgradeRequest() is not valid for [javax.websocket (JSR356)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html).

Comment: Thanks, I pasted the wrong reference. It's org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session

Comment: The asker mentioned use of jsr356.  the jetty native websocket api isn't going help him.